# Download File with Ruby Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am trying to save a file with mechanize. The script I've included enables me to download a file with the correct name, but there is no content. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? Here is the resource that I am using.

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize/File

Any help would be great! Thank you!

```
require 'mechanize'

uri = URI 'http://website.com/page.html'
file = Mechanize::File.new uri, nil, ''
filename = file.save
puts filename
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not see it used that way.  Normally you need to create an agent, then issue the get.

try this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

uri = URI 'http://website.com/page.html'
agent = Mechanize.new
file = agent.get uri

filename = file.save  # saves to page.html
puts filename         # page.html
```

Answer (score 4):

```
mecha = Mechanize.new
file = mecha.get(uri)
filename = file.save
```

You shouldn't be constructing the `File` object, since it's empty. It is intended to be constructed by Mechanize when it fetches an object.